# Ground hitting system

Tags: collision-detection, physics, platformer

I want to know how to make character hit ground and lose health. For example: when character is falling of one meter he losing only a small part of his health, and when he's falling of 10 metters he dying.

I just want to know if it's about speed or distance or maybe even time? (If you can implement some code. please.)

P.S. I'm planning to use SFML and C++.

Comment: This is a design decision. What factors you want to include in the damage algorithm for hitting the ground are up to you. Keeping track of the distance fallen is probably going to be more difficult than just using the speed when the character hits, but it's your choice. Simply create an event when your character hits the ground, pass in the speed (or distance fallen) and calculate a health loss.

Comment: Either use time to set a timer flag when the character starts falling, then when he hits the ground, calculate time elapsed, or use distance - simply calculate the distance between the character's position and the ground. Or better yet, combine the two. Algorithm to calculate distance is easily found on google.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Are you just asking for the code? I don't want to be rude, but you won't find anyone willing to write the code for you.

Instead, try different approaches and see how far you get. You might be surprised to see where you get.

You could try to give the character a boolean value to see if it's falling or not. If it's falling, every tile of free fall, store one hearth of damage in a temporary variable and when he hits the ground, take the life from the character.

Again, try different approaches and see what works for you. Asking for the code won't give you the answer you want.

Comment: **"If you want"** that means the code is an optional thing.

Comment: It's actually "If you can". Nevertheless, he's not pointing to a specific issue.